# What is the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q^c\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathfrak p$ a prime of $K$. Let $\mathbb Q^c$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb C$. If $L$ is a number field containing $K$ then $L\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$ is a product of fields $\prod_{\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p}L_\mathfrak P$

What can we say about $V=\mathbb Q^c\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$? Is it also a product of fields?

Also in his book 'Galois Modules' Frohlich defines the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q^c\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$ as the *integral closure* of $\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}$ inside the tensor product.

Presumably $\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}$ sits inside $\mathbb Q^c\otimes_{\mathcal O_K} \mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}=V$ but how would an element of $\mathbb Q^c\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$  integral over $\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}$ actually look like?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237893/what-is-the-ring-of-integers-in-mathbb-qc-otimes-k-k-mathfrak-p